# How can I get the Value from a select tag with option and optgroups?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hey I need to get the value from a Select Tag with 2 `optgroups` and some options

here is my html:

```
<select id="rackSelect" @dataChange="rack=$event" label="Rack Units">
  <option disabled selected>Choose a Rack Unit</option>
  <optgroup label="Rack Space">
    <option value = "quarter">1/4 Rack</option>
    <option value = "half">1/2 Rack</option>
    <option value = "full" >Full Rack</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Individual Rack Units">
    <option value="1" data-rack_cost="65">1 Rack Unit</option>
    <option value="2" data-rack_cost="130">2 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="3" data-rack_cost="195">3 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="4" data-rack_cost="260">4 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="5" data-rack_cost="325">5 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="6" data-rack_cost="390">6 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="7" data-rack_cost="455">7 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="8" data-rack_cost="520">8 Rack Units</option>
    <option value="9" data-rack_cost="585">9 Rack Units</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I need the value of a switch case.

```
rackBeautiful(): string | undefined {
  switch (this.rack) {
    case 'quarter':
      this.rack = "quarter";
      break;

    case 'half':
      return 'half rack';
    case 'full':
      return 'full rack';
    default:
      if (isNaN(this.rack))
        return 'immer default?';
      else
        return ' Rack Units';
  }
}
```

And I am using vue.js without jQuery.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Please check my answer to get both `option and optgroup`

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution using vueJs :
just add v-model and add method @change:

```
<select id="rackSelect" v-model="selectedVal" @change="showVal" label="Rack Units">***your options***</select>
```

jsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/3966/

Comment: I just realize OP want `select tag with option and optgroups` both

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `vue.js`, you can make use of the `v-model` directive, which creates the two-way data binding for you.

So add it like this:

```
<select id="rackSelect" @change="updateVal" label="Rack Units" v-model="selected">
   <!-- your options go here -->
</select>
```

And then declare the `selected` variable in your Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: ''
  }
  methods: {
    updateVal(){
      switch (this.selectedVal) {
        case 'quarter':
          this.selectedVal = "quarter";
          break;

        case 'half':
          return 'half rack';
        case 'full':
          return 'full rack';
        default:
        if (isNaN(this.selectedVal))
          return 'immer default?';
        else
          return ' Rack Units';
     }
   }
})
```

---

Edit: Here's a live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vmf8tg5q/

Comment: Select2 removes `select` tag

Comment: can you make this as a live demo ?

Comment: @OIIO added one

Comment: I just realize OP want `select tag with option and optgroups` both

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` will give you only select value, if you want `optgroup` you can do like this.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    item:'',
    group:''
  },
  methods:{
    getVal: function(){
      var rack = document.querySelector("#rackSelect");
      this.item = rack.value;
      this.group =  rack.options[rack.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<select id="rackSelect" @change="getVal" label="Rack Units" >
                  <option disabled selected>Choose a Rack Unit</option>
                  <optgroup label="Rack Space">
                    <option value = "quarter">1/4 Rack</option>
                    <option value = "half">1/2 Rack</option>
                    <option value = "full" >Full Rack</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Individual Rack Units">
                    <option value="1" data-rack_cost="65">1 Rack Unit</option>
                    <option value="2" data-rack_cost="130">2 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="3" data-rack_cost="195">3 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="4" data-rack_cost="260">4 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="5" data-rack_cost="325">5 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="6" data-rack_cost="390">6 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="7" data-rack_cost="455">7 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="8" data-rack_cost="520">8 Rack Units</option>
                    <option value="9" data-rack_cost="585">9 Rack Units</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
                
<div>Group : {{group}}</div>
<div>Item : {{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can work with vueJs only , why including all this libs !!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
var val = document.getElementById('rackSelect').value
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/y8bpjgpc/1/

Comment: no sorry, i tried this in the console and get "undefined" back

Comment: Did you forget the closing bracket from the select in your code too? In your example it's </select instead of </select>

Comment: Select2 removes `select` tag

Comment: This answer completely ignores the fact that this question is about [tag:vue]. One of the reasons why vue questions shouldn't also be tagged with [tag:javascript].